# Getting a file extension from dropbox or driver after onActivityResult()

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I use this code for upload file:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final String path = getPath(data.getData());
        final String fileExt = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }
}
```

This code work fine for select file from `SDCard`. But if I select file from `Drive` or `Dropbox` on line 4 I get error.

Anyone knows why it happens like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code work fine for select file from SDCard.

Not necessarily. After all, files do not have to have extensions. `README` is a valid filename, and it does not have a file extension.

> But if I select file from Drive or Dropbox on line 4 I get error

Sure. There is no requirement for a `Uri` to have a file extension. For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53131985/android-get-extension-file-from-dropbox-or-driver-after-onactivityresult` is a `Uri`, and it does not have a file extension.

If `data.getData().getScheme()` returns `file`, you are welcome to try your algorithm, but it will fail for `README`.

If `data.getData().getScheme()` returns `content`, you can use `getContentResolver().getType(data.getData())` to get a MIME type for the content. You can then try to use `MimeTypeMap` to identify a file extension, though `MimeTypeMap` does not handle all possible MIME types.

Overall, you need to revise your plans, such that you do not need file extensions.

Comment: I have a doubt not related to OP. But, here goes: Now that google will work on androidx packages now and in coming future, is there any way to get android packages by default in our project? I mean without having to click **Refactor to Androidx** thingy?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån: If you have unrelated questions, click the "Ask Question" button and ask a separate Stack Overflow question. Most likely, some future version of Android Studio will set up its new-project templates to use AndroidX artifacts -- I do not know when.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to ask as a new question.. Anyway thanks for the reply, I actually follow many of your answers and Posts to learn. I'm waiting for Android to launch something like that... Thanks anyway..